# Richfaces Model Panel Not Working in commandButton/Link With HigherVersion of browser

Tags: jsf, model, richfaces, panel, commandlink

I m trying to call a model Panel through CommandButton in Windows Vista Mozilla Firefox:-Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.11) Gecko/20101012 Firefox/3.6.11 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)

When Ever i m clicking On the CommandButton IT is showing a blank white Page and its look like Browser Serching anything.and No any bean calling and also no any exception is coming

```
<a4j:commandLink id="showItem" action="#{addCompWL.addCompanynavigation}" 
        onclick="Richfaces.showModalPanel('addWatchListCompanyPanel',{width:500, top:200});"
        actionListener="#{addCompWL.addCompany}"
        rerender="modalPanelDiv" value="Add Stock to Watch List">
         <f:attribute name="companyId" value="#{navigationBean._company_id}"/>
         <f:attribute name="companyName" value="#{navigationBean._companyName}"/>
         <a4j:ajaxListener type="org.ajax4jsf.ajax.ForceRender" />
        </a4j:commandLink>
```

i m using jsf1.2,Richfaces3.3.2.SR1,Preetyfaces3.0.2

ThANKS

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is better to display the Modal Panel after the Ajax call is made?

```
<a4j:commandLink id="showItem" action="#{addCompWL.addCompanynavigation}" 
    oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('addWatchListCompanyPanel',{width:500, top:200});"
    ...
```

Other point: you have a `rerender="modalPanelDiv"`. What is `modalPanelDiv` exactly? Is it the `modalPanel` itself, a `div` that contains the `modalPanel` or a `div` inside the `modalPanel`?

Comment: <a4j:commandButton id="showItem" action="#{addCompWL.addCompanynavigation}"  
        oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('addWatchListCompanyPanel',{width:500, top:200});"
        actionListener="#{addCompWL.addCompany}" value="Add Stock to Watch List">
         <f:attribute name="companyId" value="#{navigationBean._company_id}"/>
         <f:attribute name="companyName" value="#{navigationBean._companyName}"/>
        </a4j:commandButton>

Comment: Why do you have an action **and** an actionListener on your button? You must use only one of them...